# get_post_meta returning no value in custom post type alert email

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, email

I am working on a function that will alert a user via email when a custom post type (glossary_post) has been created on the frontend of my site. It is working well except I need to get the value of a CPT (glossary_tag) to print out in the message of the email and it is returning nothing. My code:

***Edited I got this working with the below code but am not sure if it is the correct way to do it.***

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'pending_post_status', 10, 3 );

function pending_post_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

  $author_id=$post->post_author;
  $address = get_the_author_meta('user_login', $author_id);
  $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
  $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
  $edit_author = $user_info->user_login;
  $term_list = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'glossary_tag', '', '& ' ));

if ( ( $new_status === "pending" ) && ( $post->post_type == 'glossary_post' ) ){

  $post_title = $post->post_title; 
  $to = 'XXXXXX.com';
  $subject = 'A Glossary term has been created'; 
  $message = 'A new Glossary term named "' . $post_title . '" has been created in the category "' . $term_list . '" by ' . $address . '. Please login at XXXXX to review and then publish if acceptable.';

  wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message ); 
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `glossary_tag` is a meta key and not taxonomy slug? If so, are you certain the meta key is correctly spelled?

Comment: It is a custom taxonomy so I tried $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'glossary_tag' ); and that is still returning blank

Comment: I think it is better to use `display_name` instead of `user_login` it should be secret

Comment: While I do agree with you, it’s for an an office only intranet where users don’t have a display name just their email login